# Can human psychics affect Saurians?

Tags: conspiracy-x

Basically I want to hit a Saurian base with satellite Alexis but we cannot find clear information if it will work and how well.

Gaming with the original system but question should be valid for all three versions of the game.

Comment: @KRyan could you add 'con-x' as a synonym to the 'conspiracy-x' tag? It is a very common abbreviation.

Comment: @Len I've added the synonym.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have my first edition books in front of me, but from 2nd edition, and I believe 1st, Saurians are just treated as psychic voids. So the attempt to affect them with Alexis will suffer the same restrictions and penalties that a human psychic would. So no reading auras, but telepathy is possible, just harder.

Comment: Brilliant, my other sources have said much the same. Enjoy the bounty, don't spend it all at once.